# How to use Predict() a linear model given the value of B1

Tags: r

```r
library(wooldridge)
library(tidyverse)
library(stargazer)
setwd("C:/Users/Charlie/Desktop/R Homework")

data(wage1)

reg_wage1 <- lm(lwage ~ female + educ + (female * educ), data = wage1)

stargazer(reg_wage1, type = "text")

female_at_zero <- data.frame(female=0)
pred <- predict(reg_wage1, female_at_zero)

stargazer(pred, type = "text")
```

My problem is when I try to run this code it keeps asking me to put in a value for educ, but I do not want to change education, I only want to see the model's results in stargazer if female is equal to 0.

Comment: Hi Charles Reid and welcome to Stack Overflow. Since your model formula depends on `female` and `educ` you should provide an input for `educ`. Otherwise your model can't give you a prediction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you're running into is that you've defined your model `reg_wage1` with `educ` so it won't know how to make a prediction without an `educ` value. `lm` has defined the `female` variable based on the values of the `educ` variable (not to mention the interacted variable you added to the model). If you want to see the effect on `lwage` with just `female = 0`, you're going to have to redefine your model.

Another option is to simply call `female_at_zero <- data.frame(female = 0, educ = 0)`. By setting `educ` to 0, you're essentially looking at just the effect of `female`. But this solution is redundant because the value of `pred` will simply be the value of `Constant` from the output of `stargazer(reg_wage1, type = "text")`. This is due to the fact that a linear model (`lm`) defines its intercept (`Constant`) as the point at which all independent variables are equal to 0.